# copy App.config when compiling with CodeAnalysis.Compilation.Emit

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am compiling a C# project using the Roslyn CodeAnalysis APIs, as in the following snipet:

```
...
EmitResult emitResult = null;
using (FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
  emitResult = compilation.Emit(outputFileStream, null);
}
...
```

This works perfectly. However, when I want to compile an executable project that contains an App.Config file, this file is not emitted in the output directory (similar to how it is emitted when compiling via Visual Studio), which is problematic if you want to parse some configs from that file at runtime.

I realize that it should not be emitted by default, but I would probably need to enable some option, or to somehow extract the App.Config path from the Project object and emit it myself? I cannot seem to find any information regarding this, and the Project class does not seem to contain any information regarding config files (unless I am missing something).

Is there some specific API that I need to use to achieve the above? Any pointers to existing code that does this available?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Roslyn is not a build system, it's a compiler. It can *only* transform code into assemblies (and PDBs). When you compile a `.csproj` in Visual Studio, MSBuild reads all the properties and items in the project file and translates them into a series of steps that, among other things, call the Roslyn compiler, copies `App.config` files to the output directory, copies references, etc.

While it's true Roslyn can read MSBuild project files, it only uses this information for compilation purposes, such as locating references.

So, if you're dynamically compiling assemblies, you'll have to copy the `App.config` file yourself (note - VS doesn't emit this file - it just copies and renames it).

Comment: One slight correction: there's also all sorts of mutations that might happen to the app.config for binding redirects and other systems. If it matters to the scenario, you might just have to invoke MSBuild.